# ViewChild element not working as expected

Tags: angular, html5-canvas, viewchild

So actually what I want to do is simple I need to reference a canvas element from template in the typescript file

The code I use is
`@ViewChild('myCanvas', { static: true }) myCanvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;`
But it shows an error saying the variable has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

And if I add "!" or ":any" my below code won't work
What I meant by my code "won't" work isn't that ngcc will signal a compilation error But instead what I want to do below needs the variable to be different from null or undefined or any

I ask because I once used the above code in another Angular Version and it worked fine
Now I'm using Angular 13

Answer (score 0):

```js
@ViewChild('myCanvas', { static: true }) myCanvas!: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;
```

This one will "force" the compiler to accept that this variable is defined.

```js
@ViewChild('myCanvas', { static: true }) myCanvas: any;
```

This one will remove the typing on your variable, effectively removing the intellisense of your IDE too.

But both of them should work. If they don't, please reproduce the issue on stackblitz.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your your answer already... what I meant by my code "won't" work wasn't that ngcc will signal a compilation error

But instead what I want to do below needs the variable to be different from null or undefined or any